# Trying to insert value to database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database

i just want to basic insert some text to my database but why it show this error? but in my friend computer it work...
(i already do the table for the database)

An explicit value for the identity column in table 'CUSTOMER' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

```
public partial class SignUp : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LENOVO\\EBG; Initial Catalog=dbMACARON; integrated security= True");
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from CUSTOMER");
    public void Bind()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        da.Fill(ds, "CUSTOMER");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //SUBMIT SIGNUP
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand comi = new SqlCommand("Insert CUSTOMER values(@name,@nric,@address,@gender,@dob,@phone,@email,@username,@password)");
    comi.Parameters.Add("name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    comi.Parameters["name"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
    comi.Parameters.Add("nric", SqlDbType.Char, 12);
    comi.Parameters["nric"].Value = TextBox2.Text;
    comi.Parameters.Add("address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    comi.Parameters["address"].Value = TextBox3.Text;
    comi.Parameters.Add("gender", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
    comi.Parameters["gender"].Value = TextBox4.Text;
    comi.Parameters.Add("dob", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    comi.Parameters["dob"].Value = TextBox5.Text;
    comi.Parameters.Add("phone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    comi.Parameters["phone"].Value = TextBox6.Text;
    comi.Parameters.Add("email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    comi.Parameters["email"].Value = TextBox7.Text;
    comi.Parameters.Add("username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    comi.Parameters["username"].Value = TextBox8.Text;
    comi.Parameters.Add("password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    comi.Parameters["password"].Value =TextBox9.Text;
    comi.Connection = con;
    comi.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Bind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks you everyone for helping me, i have solve my problem already. thanks you. @

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This error happens when you are trying to insert a new record into a table that contains an identity column without specifying the columns in the INSERT statement and you are assigning a value to the identity column instead of letting SQL Server assign the value.

you are missing `into` in insert query should be

Setting the `IDENTITY_INSERT to ON` for the table allows explicit values to be inserted into the identity column of a table

```
Insert into CUSTOMER (name,nric,address,gender,dob,phone,email,username,password) values (@name,@nric,@address,@gender,@dob,@phone,@email,@username,@password)");

comi.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",TextBox1.Text);
comi.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nric",TextBox2.Text);
comi.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address",TextBob3.Text);
comi.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", TextBox4.Text);
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was on database table create.. IDENTITY_INSERT is ON. is mean your field was created in integer type and it will +1 automatic on each entry user do not need to insert to this field when execute insert statement. if you do so, "explicit value for the identity column " will occur, please do check your database create is same to your friend or not. hope this is helpful for you. good luck

Comment: yes i was trying to make my custid set as identity like i put on my database Cust_ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) , but on my asp.net i didt put any value on it.. but only to fetch ... but i still get this identity error..

Answer (score 0):

Here if you have an identity column in database like id etc then  you should specify columns name in insert statement like.

```
Insert CUSTOMER(name,nric,address,gender,dob,phone,email,username,password)
values(@name,@nric,@address,@gender,@dob,@phone,@email,@username,@password)
```

Answer (score 0):

try out like this example

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT CUSTOMER ON;" + 
               "insert into CUSTOMER(a,b,c) " + 
                "values(@a,@b,@c;" + 
                "SET IDENTITY_INSERT CUSTOMER OFF;" ;
```

comi.Parameters.Add("@a", "a");
 comi.Parameters.Add("@b", "b");
 comi.Parameters.Add("@c", "c");